# free a collection from null references immediately

Tags: java, arrays, null, hashset

Is there a very fast way to remove all the null references from a collection?

I mean:

```
HashSet<String> outCollection = new HashSet<String>();

outCollection.add("Hello,");
outCollection.add("who");
outCollection.add(null);
outCollection.add("are");
outCollection.add("you?");
```

I created a method like this but clearly it won't work:

```
for(String s : outCollection) 
{
    if(s == null) 
        outCollection.remove(s);
}
```

but it pops up a "CurrentModificationException". I'm forced to use an HashSet.

I would like to have something like this when printed:

```
["how", "Hello," "are", "you?"]  //Free from null references.
```

Comment: In java 8:  `removeIf(new Predicate<Object>(){@Override public boolean test(Object val){return null==val;}});`

Answer (score 1):

How about `while(myCollection.remove(null));`

The `remove()` method returns true if something was removed, so you can remove all the nulls (or any elements) with that oneliner. Avoids `ConcurrentModificationException` and works for all collections that implement `remove(Object o)` (which is all of them, or at least the common ones).

Answer (score 1):

Try remove(object o):

outCollection.remove(null);

Comment: I think this will only remove one `null`.  There could be multiple `null`s in a list.

Comment: There are no different `nulls`. This removes all `nulls` in this collection.

Comment: The javadoc - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove(java.lang.Object) - "Removes a single instance of the specified element from this collection, if it is present (optional operation)."  The optional operation means it is not strictly speaking guaranteed to remove a single `null` even if multiple `null`s are present.